# Problem with read data from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

i'm trying to read data from a JSON file have some information below (i only want to read `customer_info`). But the list i get alwasy gives me the data of the second (or last) customer in the JSON file (the name of the `Food` will be the second food of the second customer). I don't know why please help me thank you

Json file

```
{
    "customer_info": [
        {
            "Table ID" : "0001",
            "Food":[
                {"Name": "Pizza", "Amount": "2", "Price":"4"},
                {"Name": "Chicken", "Amount": "3", "Price":"7.5"}
            ],
            "Total bill" : "200",
            "Time order" : "6:00pm",
            "Time by sec" : "0183287783",
            "Status" : "Paid"
        },
        {
            "Table ID" : "0003",
            "Food":[
                {"Name": "Hamburger", "Amount": "2", "Price":"4.4"},
                {"Name": "Soup", "Amount": "3", "Price":"7.5"}
            ],
            "Total bill" : "200",
            "Time order" : "6:00pm",
            "Time by sec" : "0183287783",
            "Status" : "Paid"
        }
    ],
    "food_initial_info":[
        {
            "Name" : "Pizza",
            "Price" : "2"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Fried Chicken",
            "Price": "1.8"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Soup",
            "Price": "2.5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Beef",
            "Price": "4.2"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Spaghetti",
            "Price": "3.5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Hamburger",
            "Price": "2.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python file

```
import json
import time

class Food:
    name = ""
    price = ""
    amount = ""
    food_own_bill = ""
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def food_bill(self):
        self.food_own_bill =str(int(self.price) * int(self.amount))

class Customer:
    table_id = ""
    food = []
    total_bill = ""
    time_order = ""
    time_by_sec = ""
    status = ""

    def __init__(self, table_id, food, time_order, time_by_sec, status):
        self.table_id = table_id
        self.time_order = time_order
        self.time_by_sec = time_by_sec
        self.status = status
        for item in food:
            self.food.append(item) 
    
    def calculate_bill(self):
        bill = 0
        for item in self.food:
            bill += item.food_bill()
    

def load_customer_info(fileName):
    with open (fileName) as filejson:
        data = json.load(filejson)
    listcustomer = []
    for item in data["customer_info"]:
        new_customer = Customer
        new_customer.table_id = item["Table ID"]
        new_customer.total_bill = item["Total bill"]
        new_customer.time_order = item["Time order"]
        new_customer.time_by_sec = item["Time by sec"]
        new_customer.status = item["Status"]
        
        for food_info in item["Food"]:
            new_food = Food
            new_food.name = food_info["Name"]
            new_food.amount = food_info["Amount"]
            new_food.food_own_bill = food_info["Price"]
            new_customer.food.append(new_food)           
        listcustomer.append(new_customer)
    return listcustomer

listcustomer = load_customer_info("data.json")
print(listcustomer[0].food[0].name)
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Did you mean: `new_customer = Customer()`?

Comment: Until now i just want to read the data into a list of Customer

Comment: @quamrana i tried using the ```__init__``` function too but it still doesn't work

Comment: You should also remove all the lines between `class Customer:` and `def __init__():`

Comment: Using the `__init__()` method is the way to go.

Comment: ah yes thanks so much. I change the way assigning by using ```__init__()``` for both of the classes and it works

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).